# Plugging Google Account users to administrate a Windows Azure subscription?

Tags: g-suite, azure

I would like to know if it is possible - and how - to define a list a Google Apps users as a list of co-administrators of a Windows Azure subscription? Basically, the process would be equivalent to replacing the Microsoft Live authentication by the Google authentication.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn308591.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that this is possible.

At the moment only Microsoft accounts or users in the subscription's default Windows Azure AD directory can be configured as co-administrators.

I believe The link posted by @ceejayoz talks about configured SSO to Google Apps from WaaD, which is more about using WaaD users to access Google Apps